# Polar Equations of Ellipse

Tags: conic-sections, polar-coordinates

I currently have the equation:
$$1=\frac{x^2}{75}+\frac{y^2}{56.25}$$

 for my ellipse and I have found the values such as the foci($2.5\sqrt{3}, 0$) and ($-2.5\sqrt{3}, 0$) with the eccentricity of 0.5. I have translated this into the form of $r=\frac{ep}{1-ecos(x)}$
$\Rightarrow r=\frac{3.75}{1-0.5cos(x)}$

 I understand that this is the correct shape for my ellipse but it does not have the original center at the origin, which is the reason to why I am asking this question. How can I show algebraically rearranging my Cartesian formula to polar formula and still maintain my center at the origin?

Comment: You used the wrong polar form equation. That one is relative to a focus. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_forms.

Answer (score 3):

To pass to polar coordinates use the change of variable $x=r\cos(t)$, $y=r\sin(t)$.

The equation of the ellipse becomes

$$1=r^2\left(\cos^2(t)/75+\sin^2(t)/56.25\right)$$

Comment: I don't believe this is correct

Answer (score 1):

Given the ellipse

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

there are several ways to express it in the complex plane. Some are shown in the other answers. Here are two direct expressions for $z(\theta),~\theta\in[0,2\pi]$.

$$
z=a\cos\theta+ib\sin\theta
$$
$$
r=\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta}}
$$
$$
z=re^{i\theta}
$$

P.S. I gave the same answer to your about how to express this particular ellipse in Cartesian coordinates. However, let me add here that in the first form $\theta$ is a *parameter*, whereas in the second form it is actually the polar angle.